# How do I bundle Ruby Scripts with my JAR and get make calls to them

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I'd like to bundle some Ruby Scripts with my jar, nothing too fancy just some standard regex processing and log processing.

I don't want to force my scripts to live outside the JAR.

Calls to the scripts are nothing more than asking the scripts to run top to bottom with a couple or arguments.

I currently distribute my app in two parts, a jar and scripts in a zip but I don't want to do this.

Can JRuby help me? Is there another way?

I'd like to do something like

```
//Java Code
exec("ruby script arguments");
// Java Code
```

any help?

Comment: This might be helpful - https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/DirectJRubyEmbedding

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to look at the 'StandaloneJarsAndClasses" part of the JRuby project on github.  It reads, "You may also want to bundle JRuby plus your own Ruby code into a single .jar file that when run launches your application...."

https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/StandaloneJarsAndClasses